# Does Azure app service initializing SSH using app service extension vscode?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to initializing SSH by using vscode app service extension

**12:09:04 PM: [Tunnel] Pinging app default url...
12:09:08 PM: [Tunnel] Ping responded with status code: 503
12:09:19 PM: [Tunnel] Checking status, body: {"port":2222,"state":"STOPPED","canReachPort":false,"msg":"Unable to connect to WebApp"}**

When i am using azure web host ssh sometimes its work and sometimes show error

**connect EHOSTUNREACH**

What i want to do i need to deploy my node react app

Answer (score 0):

EHOSTUNREACH means that no route to that particular host could be found. You may want to check your network setup.

Also, your method should not have been asynchronous, it should be declared as `function()` instead of `function(done)`.

Here is a similar [issue](http://bucksbits.net/2016/04/03/error-ehostunreach-when-connecting-local-node-js-and-database/) you could refer to.